# IIS6 Metabase and Configuration Compatibility feature install fails on Windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7

I'm trying to install the "IIS6 Metabase and Configuration Compatibility" feature on my Windows 7 Pro (64 bit) machine so I can use IIS with my VS2010 installation.

Unfortunately, every time I go to install said update from 'Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features On or Off', it fails with the error message "One or more of the features could not be installed". This is the only feature I'm trying to install, and it is the only one that throws an error. I have already followed the guidelines this user posted here (http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7programs/thread/6f3e6f94-ea61-4527-ab7e-cc1a3d1b1f93), none of which worked.

I was able to find an error log file at "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" containing some relevant information to what the problem might be, but I can't make any sense of it.

Some excerpts below:

```
....
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: IIS-Performance, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: DetectUpdate, Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Local Parent: IIS-WebServerRole, Intended State: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating applicability block(detectUpdate part), disposition is: Staged, applicability: Applicable, result applicability state: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: IIS-WebServerManagementTools, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: DetectUpdate, Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Local Parent: IIS-WebServerManagementTools, Intended State: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating applicability block(detectUpdate part), disposition is: Staged, applicability: Applicable, result applicability state: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:01, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Appl: DetectUpdate, Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Remote Parent: IIS-WebServerRole, Intended State: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating applicability block(detectUpdate part), disposition is: Staged, applicability: Applicable, result applicability state: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: IIS-FTPServer, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find localized custom property bag [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2011-02-13 16:14:15, Info                  CBS    Update: Setting Install State, Package: Microsoft-Windows-SimpleTCP-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: SimpleTCP, new state: On
2011-02-13 16:14:15, Info                  CBS    Update: Setting Install State, Package: Microsoft-Windows-SimpleTCP-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: SimpleTCP, current State: On, new state: On
2011-02-13 16:14:15, Info                  CBS    Update: Setting Install State, Package: Microsoft-Windows-SNMP-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: SNMP, new state: Off
2011-02-13 16:14:15, Info                  CBS    Update: Setting Install State, Package: Microsoft-Windows-SNMP-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: SNMP, current State: Off, new state: Off
2011-02-13 16:14:15, Info                  CBS    Update: Setting Install State, Package: Microsoft-Windows-WMI-SNMP-Provider-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, Update: WMISnmpProvider, new state: Off
...
...
2011-02-13 16:14:36, Info                  CSI    00000182 Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 22 (0x0000000000000016) (sequence 321)
    Old component: [l:0]""
    New component: [ml:310{155},l:308{154}]"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Metabase, Culture=neutral, Version=6.1.7600.16385, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Installer ID: {51d504ad-4868-464c-a504-e6cc8a210a97}
    Installer name: [7]"Service"
2011-02-13 16:14:36, Info                  CSI    00000183@2011/2/13:21:14:36.133 CSI Advanced installer perf trace:
CSIPERF:AIDONE;{51d504ad-4868-464c-a504-e6cc8a210a97};Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Metabase, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral;4410
2011-02-13 16:14:36, Info                  CSI    00000184 End executing advanced installer (sequence 321)
    Completion status: S_OK 

2011-02-13 16:14:36, Info                  CSI    00000185 Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 23 (0x0000000000000017) (sequence 322)
    Old component: [l:0]""
    New component: [ml:310{155},l:308{154}]"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Metabase, Culture=neutral, Version=6.1.7600.16385, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Installer ID: {81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c}
    Installer name: [15]"Generic Command"
2011-02-13 16:14:36, Info                  CSI    00000186 Calling generic command executable (sequence 22 (0x00000016)): [40]"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe"
    CmdLine: [60]""C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install Metabase"
2011-02-13 16:14:43, Info                  CSI    00000187 Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  LockComponentPath (10): flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:28b9f308c3cbcb010c0100006004880c} pathid: {l:16 b:28b9f308c3cbcb010d0100006004880c} path: [l:234{117}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.s..ation.badcomponents_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_3868158f24725705" pid: 460 starttime: 129421045041308447 (0x01cbcbc13825a31f)
2011-02-13 16:14:43, Info                  CSI    00000188 Creating NT transaction (seq 10), objectname [6]"(null)"
2011-02-13 16:14:43, Info                  CSI    00000189 Created NT transaction (seq 10) result 0x00000000, handle @0x740
2011-02-13 16:14:44, Info                  CSI    0000018a@2011/2/13:21:14:44.605 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;662198
2011-02-13 16:14:44, Error                 CSI    0000018b (F) Done with generic command 22 (0x00000016); CreateProcess returned 0, CPAW returned S_OK
    Process exit code 15 (0x0000000f) resulted in success? FALSE
    Process output: [l:22 [22]"Failed = 0x8009000f

"][gle=0x80004005]
2011-02-13 16:14:44, Info                  CSI    0000018c@2011/2/13:21:14:44.606 CSI Advanced installer perf trace:
CSIPERF:AIDONE;{81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c};Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Metabase, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral;8854045
2011-02-13 16:14:44, Error      [0x018007] CSI    0000018d (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: Generic Command ({81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c}) with HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14109).  Failure will not be ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the installer queue are completed; installer is reliable (2)[gle=0x80004005]
2011-02-13 16:14:44, Info                  CSI    0000018e End executing advanced installer (sequence 322)
    Completion status: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ADVANCED_INSTALLER_FAILED) 
...
```

This is a mission critical issue for me; any advice would be greatly appreciated.

- Dave

Answer (score 0):

Not only you find the error non sense, I find it useless as well.

80004005 means generic error, and you have to contact Microsoft support team via http://support.microsoft.com for assistance.

The quickest way may be rebuild this box.

Comment: Thus far, I've ended up having to resort to avoiding usage of IIS. Not ideal, but since I planned to use it for Visual Studio development, there was at least an alternative (VS ASP.NET dev server). Unfortunately so, but your suggested solution matches up to the only known resolution I've heard of.